# Delete row in sqlite on specific time without open the application

Tags: android, sqlite, time, android-sqlite

I need to delete a row in `sqlite` database on specific time, exactly in midnight.

I do like the following code :

```
Calendar currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date currentTime = currentCalendar.getTime();

Calendar setCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
setCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
setCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
setCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
Date setTime = setCalendar.getTime();

if(currentTime.after(setTime)){
// do another task
}else{
databaseHandler.deleteRow(String.valueOf(listSession.get(0).getId()));
}
```

With code above, the row is deleted but i have to open the application first.

My question is : **Is there any possibility how to delete row is sqlite without open the apps? If any, how?**

Comment: You can use the AlarmManager to trigger a background Service

Comment: Why do you care if the row is deleted when nobody is actually looking at the database file? Just delete it when your app is started.

Comment: @CL : it's a session. When day reach out the midnight, the database should be deleted automatically (without open apps)

Comment: This does not answer my question. Why would it be a problem if an outdated session record is still in the database, when you delete it before you actually use the database later?

Answer (score 1):

You can use AlarmManager. First create a BroadcastReceiver.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  //Delete your row here.
}
```

Then set an alarm for it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 60000, pendingIntent);
```

Don't forget to add your receiver to your manifest file.

```
<receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion sir. Btw, is the row will deleted in every new days? Time 00:00

Comment: You can use `alarmManager.setInexactRepeating()` method instead of `alarmManager.set()`

Answer (score 0):

Create a android service and BroadcastReceiver and put your above code in onreceive function of BroadcastReceiver and call this BroadcastReceiver in onstart function of service.